# Problems with finding Three20 Header Files for iPhone App

Tags: iphone, three20

I am trying to create an app using three20 for a photo viewer. When I follow the instructions on their site (which is now simply running a python script) it seems to behave correctly but then when I try to build I get a "No such file or directory" error for using `#import <Three20/Three20.h>`.

I am pretty sure the header search path is correct, but I can't seem to get it working, even when I follow exact tutorials online.

Has anyone seen this problem before and know how to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is a decent question and it's well written. My only advice to you is "pay attention to the 'street signs'". (formatting controls, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you haven't imported the files correctly. Have another look at where you added the files to you project, if you have at all. (If not, you need to drag them into your project first!)

If you try to compile the project without the file added to the project, it will fail. Simply adding a path is not enough.

[image: A failed build]

You need to drag it into Xcode...

[image: Dragging a file into Xcode]

Add it to the project...

[image: Adding a file to a project]

And then your code should build.

[image: Succeeded build]

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to make sure you actually have added three20 into your dir. as I remember having a similar problem, when I tried to use three20 which was due to the fact it wasn't in the right place, when I thought it was.

Comment: You can avoid this problem by checking "Copy Items to Groups Folder" in the import object.